# Reading from file as stdin

Tags: c++, loops, file-io

say i have a main() function that has some commands,
for ex

```
int main()
{
  ofstream myfile;
  while(!cin.eof()){
  string command; string word;
  cin >> command;
  cin >> word;

  if (command.compare("add") == 0) {
    //do Something
   }

  if (command.compare("use") == 0){
    myfile.open(word);
    myfile >> //loop back into this loop as stdin
    myfile.close();  
  }
}
```

the contents of myfile will have a "command" "word" field for each line in the file.. I was wondering if there was a way to read the file as input and loop it back into the main() loop?

Comment: you mean like a `while` loop?

Comment: a while loop, not too sure how that will loop back with the same commands? so myfile >> cin ?

Comment: Shouldnt that be `ifstream` for reading the file?

Comment: You really need to describe your problem better, show examples of your input, describe if you are trying to be interactive or just process files.  If you are failing with this program, what was your expected result, what result you got.  Folks will just look at this once, and decide not to invest time in answering if you didnt invest time in being very details, narrowing you test case to the absolute minimum (compilable, runable example) etc ...

Comment: Rule of Thumb: If you ever say `eof()` or `close()` when dealing with iostreams, something is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Split the work:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void process(std::istream & is)
{
    for (std::string command, word; is >> command >> word; )
    {
        if (command == "add") { /* ... */ continue; }

        if (command == "include")
        {
            std::ifstream f(word);   // or "f(word.c_str())" pre-C++11

            if (!f) { /* error opening file! */ }

            process(f);
            continue;
        }

        // ...
    }
}

int main()
{
    process(std::cin);
}
```

Comment: getting an error `error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >'
    std::ifstream f(word);
`

Comment: @JohnSmith: On old compilers, you need to say `f(word.c_str())`.